# Bounding the degree of an algebraic extension containing solutions to polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field, and let $f_{1},\ldots, f_{s}$ be polynomials in $F[x_{1},\ldots, x_{t}]$. Assume that the degree of the polynomials is bounded by $d$, by which I mean, if $m$ is any term in $f_{i}$, then $m$ contains no exponent greater than $d$, for $i=1,\ldots, s$. Assume also that there is a solution to the polynomial system, so that  $f_{i}(a_{1},\ldots, a_{t})=0$ for each $i=1,\ldots, s$ and for some sequence, $(a_{1},\ldots, a_{t})$, of numbers from  the algebraic closure of $F$.

Is there some bound, $D$, depending on $t$ and $d$, such that there exists a solution, $(a_{1},\ldots, a_{t})$, satisfying $[F(a_{1},\ldots,a_{t}):F]\leq D?$ If so, what is that bound? Many thanks.

Comment: A crude bound at least when $F$ is infinite, I think is $d^t$.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239934/bounding-the-degree-of-an-algebraic-extension-containing-solutions-to-polynomial